# JQuery this remove not removing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get ANY div that's double clicked to be removed with jQuery.

I'm trying this:

```
$(this).dblclick(function() {

    alert('Was Doubled Clicked');
    $(this).remove();

});
```

I'm getting the alert but the div is not been removed.

I haven't added the div that's been clicked because I want it to be any if possible?

Why is my code not doing this?

Comment: What's `this` in `$(this).dblclick(`? The basic example works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ukjv7r09/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version will attach the event to the body and keep on deleting any double clicked div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('dblclick', 'div', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).remove();
  });
  var count = 1;
  $('.addMore').click(function(){
     $(this).before($('<div>Testing New '+count+'</div>'));
    count++;
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Testing 1</div>
<div>Testing 2</div>
<div>Testing 3</div>
<div>Testing 4</div>
<div>Testing 5</div>
<div>Testing 6</div>
<button class="addMore">+DIV</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`? What if the OP needs the clicks to bubble to other elements? Plus, divs have no default action.

Comment: Just a habit of mine to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` I believe refers to the `document` object. You don't want that. Try this

```js
$("div").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div">This is a div</div>

<div>This is another div</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1jpvev24/1/

Answer (score 0):

As you want to refer to all divs you have to write this:

```
$('div').dblclick(function() {
    alert('Was Doubled Clicked');
    $(this).remove();
});
```